# init-instantiated variables

Tags: servlets, initialization

Suppose I have an EntityManagerFactory reference instantiated within an init-method of a servlet:

StartServlet.java:

```
@WebServlet("/start")
public class StartServlet extends HttpServlet {
private EntityManagerFactory factory;
@Override
public void init() {
factory = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("jpa");
getServletContext().setAttribute("factory", factory);
}
}
```

Which I also do visible for all other servlets within the "container". Now, lets say I want to access this reference in another servlet, like:
 AnotherServlet.java:

```
@WebServlet("/another")
public class AnotherServlet extends HttpServlet {
private EntityManagerFactory factory;
@Override
public void init() {
factory = (EntityManagerFactory) getServletContext().getAttribute("factory");
if(factory == null) {
//factory not instantiated from StartServlet, what to do?
}
}
}
```

What do I do if its not instantiated from StartServlet.java (init has not been invoked)? Hope my question is precise enough!

-Superdids

Comment: You need to create your `factory` in a [`ServletContextListener`](http://www.mkyong.com/servlet/what-is-listener-servletcontextlistener-example/), not in the servlet. Although ideally it would be created by a DI framework such a Spring and injected automatically.

Comment: Java EE offers EJB for the job.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't depend on the servlet container's order of `Servlet` initialization.

Instead, do the initialization in a [`ServletContextListener`.](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/ServletContextListener.html)